# How can I set properties outside of the constructor in JS just like in Java?

Tags: javascript, oop

If I don't want to initialize all properties of a class when it is instantiated in Java it can be done like this:

```java
class Example {

    Example(int property1){
        this.setProperty1(property1);
    }

    int property1;
    int property2;

    getProperty1(){
        return this.property1;
    }

    setProperty1(int property1){
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    getProperty2(){
        return this.property2;
    }

    setProperty1(int property2){
        this.property2 = property2;
    }
}
```

In this case I don't want to initialize right away `property2` when I instantiate the `Example` class.

My question is how can I achieve the same behavior using JS classes, because in my case the following is not working, I can't set values to the `chaveDeAcesso` property:

(BTW: I'm using ESLint with the Airbnb style-guide on vscode)

```
class NotaFiscal {

  constructor(indexNotaFiscal) {
    this.indexNotaFiscal = indexNotaFiscal;
  }

  chaveDeAcesso;

  get chaveDeAcesso() {
    return this.chaveDeAcesso;
  }

  set chaveDeAcesso(chaveAcesso) {
    this.chaveDeAcesso = chaveAcesso;
  }

}
```

[Message show inside the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ4hJ.png)

Comment: `chaveDeAcsso` should have a different name than the getter and the setter.

Comment: Do notice that `get` and `set` behavior is different from Java.

Comment: Let's say that I don't want/need to use ```get chaveDeAcesso()``` and set ```set chaveDeAcesso(chaveAcesso)```, how can I still access the property ```chaveDeAcesso``` without initializing it in the constructor?!

Comment: `obj.chaveDeAcesso` to get the value `chaveDeAcesso = "something"` to set it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can simply omit the property entirely. Javascript won't complain when you try to access it, it'll just yield `undefined`, which is equivalent to "not initialising it". You can assign to the property at any later point in time, which will create it. — When using Typescript, its type checker would complain, and it would also give you an explicit syntax to *declare but not initialise*. Plain Javascript doesn't need that though. Assignment *is* declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter and getter of Javascript are different from thos of Java. A typical pattern is that you define the instance variable with underscore `_chaveDeAcesso` and after you allow access to that with setter and getter without the underscore like in the following code. These methods are on the prototype and are accessibile like that:

```
this.chaveDeAcesso=3; //call the setter when you write
let x = this.chaveDeAcesso; //cal the getter when you read
```

```js
class NotaFiscal {

  _chaveDeAcesso;

  constructor(indexNotaFiscal) {
    this.indexNotaFiscal = indexNotaFiscal;
  }

  

  get chaveDeAcesso() {
    return this._chaveDeAcesso;
  }

  set chaveDeAcesso(chaveAcesso) {
    this._chaveDeAcesso = chaveAcesso;
  }

}

let x = new NotaFiscal(1);
console.log(x._chaveDeAcesso);
x.chaveDeAcesso=5;
console.log(x._chaveDeAcesso);
```

Furthermore note that the _chaveDeAcesso defined like that isn't private, and define it like that outside the constructor is a experimental feature (you have to use babel to transpile it in es6 for instance) and may be is thi the mistake cause. Ypu can define it in the constructor without initialize it (This is superfluous, even if you omit it it will still be undefined. Inserted only to make the code more readable.). Either the cases it will be undefined:

```
constructor(indexNotaFiscal) {
    this.indexNotaFiscal = indexNotaFiscal;
    this._chaveDeAcesso = undefined; //unnecessary instruction, is already undefined. 
  }
```

Comment: `this._chaveDeAcesso;` in the constructor does absolutely zilch.

Comment: @deceze make the code clearer, namely that you have these two properties. You are right, you can omit. I put it for readibility. I emphasize this in the answer

Comment: If you want to explicitly "define" it in the constructor, at least do `this._chaveDeAcesso = undefined`, which actually does something. Otherwise it's just confusing to the reader and any linter.

Comment: Is there a reason for eslint to mark this approach as incorrect?

[This is the message shown by eslinter](https://i.imgur.com/FkaGj2l.png)

Comment: @Camilla Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713246/how-to-configure-eslint-for-es6-class-with-private-methods-correctly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385125/eslint-does-not-recognize-private-field-declaration-using-nodejs-12